# OleDbDataAdapter can't fill dataset from access table that has MEMO field

Tags: sql, ms-access, oledb

I am trying to fill a dataset by OleDbDataAdapter from MS Access DB table. All columns are fine except the MEMO column. it is truncating after 256 character.

Can anyone give me a solution?

thanks in Advance.

Shuvra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allan Browne has some excellent tips and common reasons as to why memo fields get truncated sometimes. I have been caught out before when moving to SQL server so that a look and see if that helps

http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html

Comment: Thanks kevin to sharing the link. its really heplful.